# simple HTTP client c recv() blocks

Tags: c, http, client, blocking, recv

I am try to write simple HTTP client with c , 
when i execute my program some time I gets data from website some time not.
to be specific recv() blocks, and the connection shutdown.
what the best way to deal with this problem ? I still want to get the website data.

```
ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
// Resolve the server address and port
if (iResult = getaddrinfo(s1, "http", &hints, &result)) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds

for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}


// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection

do {        
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen-1, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 ) {
         flag = 1;
         recvbuf[iResult] = '\0';
         printf("%s\n",recvbuf);
    }
    else if ( iResult == 0 ) {
            if(!flag) { 
                printf("conection close before recv data\n");
            } else {
                printf("conection close\n");
                break;
            }
    }
    else {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
} while(iResult>1);


// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

}

i've used HTTP protocol concept and sent to each url i've tried in this templet: sendbuf ="GET /[url path] HTTP 1.0/r/nHost:[www.pure_url.com]/r/n/r/n"

edit: I've tried [DaSourcerer advise] , changed to HTTP/1.1 and added Connection: close , still some time i get the data some times not.

also I added:

```
int tcp_timeout=10000;
unsigned int  sz = sizeof(tcp_timeout);
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,
(char*)&tcp_timeout, sz);
```

this idea didn't help.

Comment: Post piece of code instead of giving some links. That would help to get fast response

Answer (score 0):

I think your timeouts are too strict. Your sent headers will also provoke servers to wait for further input. Try this:

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

It also bears mentioning that `Host` is a header introduced in HTTP/1.1. It has no meaning in HTTP/1.0. You may also be interested into [RFC 7230, section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) as you are almost certainly going to encounter chunk-encoded messages in HTTP/1.1. Don't worry, though: it can be parsed with a simple state machine.